# colobox, redirect to specific page after close

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

This is the scenario:

1. I have a newsletter service, that ask me for a URL on success when getting the suscriptor´s email.
2. I´ve made a "thanks-page" in html.
3. I´ve embed colorbox that launch a simple html part inside main html.
4. I need to redirect to main site page after click in genuine close buttom (#cboxClose).

The script that launchs colorbox is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.colorbox({width:"60%", inline:true, href:"#suscripcion", transition:"fade"});
        }); 
 </script>
```

The html which is called into colorbox modal is something like this:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="suscripcion">
        <p><strong>Main Title</strong></p>
        <p>Thank you...</p>
        <ul>
        <li>Specs 1</li>
        <li>Specs 2</li>
        <li>Specs 3</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Good bye...</p>
    </div>                              
</div>
```

I don´t know how to make this, I´ve tried some examples searching "colorbox redirect...", but nothing works, so any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `click` event on `#cboxClose` this way to redirect to your main page:

```
$("#cboxClose").click(function(){
   location.href = "main-page.html";
});
```

Applying changes to the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.colorbox({width:"60%", inline:true, href:"#suscripcion", transition:"fade"});
  $("#cboxClose").click(function(){
    location.href = "main-page.html";
  });

});
```